# Эмуляция альбомной ориентации айпада в Хроме

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Следующий код запускает эмуляцию iPad'а в Хроме в книжной ориентации.
А как сделать в альбомной?

```
const {Builder, By, until} = require('selenium-webdriver');
const chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');

var driver = new Builder()
  .forBrowser('chrome')
  .setChromeOptions(new chrome.Options()
    .setMobileEmulation({deviceName: 'Apple iPad'})
    .addArguments('start-maximized')
  ).build();
```

PS: [Этот вопрос по-английски.](//stackoverflow.com/q/43319511/4928642)

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43319511/4928642

Answer (score 1):

Несложный костыль: не использовать эмуляцию, выставить желаемый размер окна и установить скроллбарам нулевую ширину. Дополнительно костыльности добавляет то, что устанавливается размер всего окна, а не размер его внутренней области:

```
let driver = new Builder()
    .forBrowser('chrome')
    .setChromeOptions(new chrome.Options()
      .addArguments('window-size=1034,893')
    )
    .build();

driver
  .get(url)
  .then(() => driver.executeScript("document.head.innerHTML+='<style>::-webkit-scrollbar{width:0px;height:0px;}::-webkit-scrollbar-button{width:0px;height:0px;}::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{background:#e1e1e1;border:0pxnone#ffffff;border-radius:50px;}::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover{background:#ffffff;}::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:active{background:#000000;}::-webkit-scrollbar-track{background:#666666;border:0pxnone#ffffff;border-radius:50px;}::-webkit-scrollbar-track:hover{background:#666666;}::-webkit-scrollbar-track:active{background:#333333;}::-webkit-scrollbar-corner{background:transparent;}</style>'"))
```

PS: Буду рад увидеть нормальные решения.